# Bash variable affectation

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have this python script :

```
    for item in users:
        User.objects.create(
                website = item['']
                myspace_name = item['']
                last_name = item['']
                public_favorites_count = item['']
                followings_count = item['']
                full_name = item['']
                user_id = item['']
                city = item['']
                first_name = item['']
                track_count = item['']
                playlist_count = item['']
                discogs_name = item['']
                followers_count = item['']
                online = item['']
                username = item['']
                description = item['']
                kind = item['']
                last_modified = item['']
                website_title = item['']
                permalink_url = item['']
                permalink = item['']
                country = item['']
                uri = item['']
                avatar_url = item['']
                plan = item['']
            )
```

The goal is to write a script to change the file like :

```
...
                    avatar_url = item['avatar_url']
                    plan = item['plan']
...
```

i tried this one but it didn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash


FILE = "/home/user/metadata.py"

clear

declare -a array
declare -i i=0

grep 'item\[' /home/user/metadata.py | while read line

do
    array[i] = $(awk '{print $1}')
    sed "s/item\['/item\['array[$i]/" 
    let i++
done
```

Any help please, to correct the script and if there is a better solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Do you really want  `plan = item['avatar_url']`, or do you want `plan = item['plan']` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `sed`. It has no input to perform the substitution on.

Comment: Learn to use your editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk one liner (easier to put it in a separate file then to figure out which quotes to escape):

```
$ cat a.awk
/.*= *item\[''\]/ {sub("''", "'"$1"'")}1

$ awk -f a.awk a.py
for item in users:
    User.objects.create(
            website = item['website']
            myspace_name = item['myspace_name']
            last_name = item['last_name']
            public_favorites_count = item['public_favorites_count']
            followings_count = item['followings_count']
            full_name = item['full_name']
            user_id = item['user_id']
            city = item['city']
            first_name = item['first_name']
            track_count = item['track_count']
            playlist_count = item['playlist_count']
            discogs_name = item['discogs_name']
            followers_count = item['followers_count']
            online = item['online']
            username = item['username']
            description = item['description']
            kind = item['kind']
            last_modified = item['last_modified']
            website_title = item['website_title']
            permalink_url = item['permalink_url']
            permalink = item['permalink']
            country = item['country']
            uri = item['uri']
            avatar_url = item['avatar_url']
            plan = item['plan']
        )
```

Comment: Thanks jas, can you tell me what the "1" dies in your awk

Comment: Yes, good question. The `1` means to print the line. As you know, every awk program is a set of patterns and actions.  If the pattern is true the corresponding action is triggered. Since `1` is always evaluated to be true, it's action is always triggered. Since there's no action present, the default action is triggered instead, and the default action is to print the line. So it's just an idiomatic awk thing that people do (and it doesn't have to be `1`, it can be anything that evaluates to true).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed "s/\([a-z_]*\) = item\[''/\1 = item['\1'/" /home/user/metadata.py
```

which uses a capturing group `\(..\)` to capture then variable name and insert it after the `item['` part.

If you'd like some tips as to why your script doesn't work, you can run it through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: your command gives this result : website = item['websitewebsite'],
change it to 
    sed "s/\([a-z_]*\) = item\['/\1 = item['/" /home/user/metadata.py
gives a correct output, i dont know why?

Comment: @Med That happens when you run it on a file you've already fixed. I've updated it so that you can run it again on fixed files without modifying them again.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable assignment syntax is incorrect. You can't have any spaces around the `=`. You also didn't feed any input to `awk`.

However, this still won't work, because the pipeline causes the `while` loop to run in a subshell, and its variable assignments won't be visible to the parent shell. Use redirection from process substitution.

But the whole thing could just be done in one `sed` command, using a backreference:

```
sed "/= item\[/s/\([^ ]*\) = item\[''\]'/\1 = item['\2']/"
```